# Map to affine formal scheme $Spf \mathbb{F}_p[[T]]$ corresponds to locally nilpotent element?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a scheme over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (but I think any ring should work) and let $X$ be the formal scheme $X=Spf\ \mathbb{F}_p[[T]]$. Something I'm reading says that a map $S \to X$ corresponds to a locally nilpotent element $t \in O_S(S)$. Why? This should be an easy question involving unwinding the definitions, but I don't fully understand the definitions for formal schemes.

A morphism $S \to X$ corresponds to a $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra homomorphism of topological rings $\mathbb{F}_p[[T]] \to O_S(S)$ (where $O_S(S)$ is given the discrete topology I guess) and so amounts to specifying the image $t \in O_S(S)$ of $T$ so that the map on rings is a map of topological rings. Somehow this translates to $t$ being locally nilponent (whatever that means, I don't know).

Comment: A linear operator $T : V \to V$ is locally nilpotent if for every $v \in V$ the sequence $T^n v$ is eventually zero (but when it is eventually zero may depend on $v$); the archetypical example is $\frac{d}{dx}$ acting on $k[x]$. This is exactly the condition needed to define power series in $T$, for example $\exp(T)$ (in characteristic zero). I'm not sure what it means for an element of a ring to be locally nilpotent, though.

Comment: Okay, so one possible definition is that an element $a \in R$ of a commutative $k$-algebra, $k$ a field, is locally nilpotent if, for every cofinite ideal $I$, the image of $a$ is nilpotent in $R/I$.